# Adding up the Integers in a HashMap/Printing the Strings (Same HashMap)

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I don't have much experience with `HashMap`'s but I was instructed to use one. I need to add up the `Integers` inside of the `HashMap` as well as print out the `Strings` existing in the same `HashMap`. The `HashMap` is declared like so

`HashMap<String, Integer> newmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

I want to add up all the Integers that I will put in (from a file read) for example if i had 100 and 50 I want the Output to say `150 total points`. ADDITIONALLY the map is also storing names of characters for example Carl and Sophia, so I want the output to say something like `Characters: Carl, Sophia`.

My problem like I said, I don't know how as I have minimal experience with `HashMap`'s. Regardless, thank you so much for responding please ask if you need any clarification! **THANKS!!**

Also, just so this question makes sense, this program's objective is to "rescue" characters/objects for points kinda like a video game. At the end it is supposed to show all the characters or objects rescued and the total points gained.

**EDIT Hero.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Hero extends Character
{
   private String heroname1;
   public Hero() {
          heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; //the default player name
   }
   HashMap<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

   public Hero(String newhero) {
          if (newhero.length() > 0) {
               heroname1 = newhero;
          } else { heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; } //defaulted as protagonist
   }

   public String getHeroName() {
          return heroname1; //return the name
   }

   public String rescue() { //class to rescue people or things
          String out = "".toString();
          for(String _key : newMap.keySet()) {
              out += heroname1 + " rescued " + _key + " " + newMap.get(_key) +!
          }
          return out;
   }

   public String toString() { //print
      return heroname1;

   }
   public String view() {
          Set<String> names = newMap.keySet();
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Characters rescued: ");
          int i = 0;
          for (String name : names) {
              if (i == 0) {
                  sb.append(name);
                  i++;
              } else {
                  sb.append(", ");
                  sb.append(name);
              }
          }
          String printNames = sb.toString();
          Collection<Integer> points = newMap.values();
          StringBuilder sp = new StringBuilder("Total points: ");
          int sum = 0;
          for (Integer value : points) {
               sum += value;
               sp.append(value);
          }
          String printPoints = sp.toString();
          return printNames + " " + printPoints ;
   }
}
```

When called by my Driver
**OUTPUT**

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!Rick Grimes rescued Michone 50pts!
Characters rescued: Carl, Michone Total points: 10050
```

**DISERED OUTPUT**

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!
Rick Grimes rescued Michone 50pts!
Characters rescued: Carl, Michone Total points: 150
```

Comment: Did you look up the `keySet()`and `values()` methods of `HashMap`?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't, would my answer be there?

Comment: Those will definitely help you, as well as probably some looping construct like a `for` loop.

Comment: @Junikin - Yes... Your answer is *definitely* there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, this is not specific to `HashMap` rather any java `Map`. To find the sum of all values, the following snippet would be handy. Please note that `Map.class` has `values()` method that returns `Collection` containing all values of the map.

```
Collection<Integer> values = myMap.values();
int sum = 0;
for (Integer value : values) {
    sum += value;
}
```

To concatenate the keys in the required format please find the code below. `Map.class` returns all keys of map as set using `keySet()` method.

```
Set<String> keys = myMap.keySet();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Characters: ");
int i = 0;
for (String key : keys) {
    if (i == 0) {
        sb.append(key);
        i++;
    } else {
        sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(key);
    }
 }
 String consolidatedKey = sb.toString();
```

Apart from this, you can do both using a same loop using `entrySet()`. This method returns a set of `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` then you could `getKey()` and `getValue()`.

Comment: Thank you that is most helpful

Comment: quick question, in my class, there already exists a toString() printing other information, will putting that last line of code in your answer in cause a problem with that?

Comment: ok. I typed in the code you suggested but instead of adding my numbers together, it sorta does that literally and gives me `10050` instead of `150`. I'll post my code so you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want both the keys and values present in a HashMap. You should look at the [entrySet()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) method. You will be able to iterate through the Map and get both key and value (score and character).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public static String view(Map newMap) {

     Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> entry=newMap.entrySet();
     StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("Characters rescued: ");
     int total=0;
     for(Entry<String,Integer> s:entry)
     {
         sb1.append(s.getKey() + ",");
         total=total+s.getValue();
     }

     sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.toString().length()-1);

     return sb1.toString() + " " + total ;
}
```